# How to create non-static, custom content in an AppBar

Tags: material-ui

I have a material-ui AppBar that sits up high in the composition, something like this:

```
<App>
  <AppBar/>
  <Main>
    <Route component={FooPage}/>
    <Route component={BarPage}/>
  </Main
</App>
```

I would like FooPage and BarPage to be able to "inject" their own content into the AppBar, such as Menus, Selects, etc. -- Without the AppBar or the component that hosts the AppBar to be specifically aware of Foo and/or Bar or any other player that does this.  I can imagine a novel way of doing it by having Foo announce to the world that "Foo is active" and having the FooBar-aware AppBar component, respond by saying "Fine...I'll render a Foo-Menu for you.."

What I want is to be able to do is pull this off without the React version of gnarly switch/case. I am pretty newish to React, and I think this is not specifically a material-ui question, but I wonder...Is there is a direct way of loading children into an AppBar (or ToolBar) where AppBar is agnostic towards its contents? And if so, what does that look like syntactically speaking?

Answer (score 0):

[AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) has two properties that can accept elements as values. As such, you could utilize the `iconElementLeft` or `iconElementRight` properties to pass in whatever element you want to display.

Check out this JSFiddle as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Asalem1/ha6v1714/26/